# how to execute rgbdslam by bag file

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm trying to execute rgbdslam offline by bag files. but I don't know that bag files I made is correct.

I found that rgbdslam subscribe 3 msgs, /camera/rgb/image_mono, /camera/rgb/points, /camera/depth/image. so I tried to create bag files in 2 ways[publish from openni_camera node].

1. rosbag record -a
2. rosbag record -O test /camera/rgb/image_mono /camera/rgb/points /camera/depth/image

but 1. occurred error in openni_node running. 2. was OK. but buffer exceed warning was occurred so It has just about 10seconds duration.

What can I do for this work.

answer anything to that. thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10476/how-to-execute-rgbdslam-by-bag-file/) by [donghwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/787/donghwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-05**:
Can you post the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For 1: `rosbag record -a` is almost always the wrong choice; it's a stupendous amount of data. Running it with openni runs you into a limitation of the driver: you can't be connected to the depth and IR streams simultaneously.

For 2: /camera/rgb/points is also a *lot* of data; roughly 300 meg/sec. That's going to fill your write buffers very quickly. See the accepted answer to [my question about RGB6D](http://answers.ros.org/question/753/rgb-6d-slam-performance-on-a-robot) for a discussion of what quality of data you need to get this working well.

You are recording the correct topics (it doesn't hurt to record /tf, as well).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0